# Go to parent route in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

Let's say I have a component that creates or edits a **thing**.

The url for the **creation** is `/things/create` and the url for **edition** is `/things/edit/4`. These routes have the same parent.

Once I fill in the form, I call some webservice and then I go back to my previous state which was `/things`.

How do I tell angular to go back to the parent route?

I could use `this.router.navigate(['../'], {relativeTo : this.route});` but `['../']` would only work for `/things/create`. For `/things/edit/4` it would go back to `/thing/edit` which doesn't exist.

This component is used in two different places, one of which has an extra step before the creation so I can't use `back()`.

Comment: cant you explicitly say router.navigate['/things'] ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that. This component would be used in two different places.

Comment: how about back() {
        this._location.back();
    }

Comment: It would work but I have one case where there is an extra step so going back would go back to this first step. I'll add this in the question.

Answer (score 3):

**Logic based on the current url**

```
if(router.url.indexOf('create')>= 0){
    this.router.navigate(['../'], {relativeTo : this.route});
 }else {
    this.router.navigate(['../../'], {relativeTo : this.route});
}
```

so if your current URL path contains the create you know you just have to go back one level, otherwise you go back two levels for the edit.

**Use Input to get base URL**

Another approach might be to have an @Input for the base URL to go back to. So each component that initializes your component has to pass it the parent url.

```
{
@Input
parentUrl;

this.router.navigate[parentUrl];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
this.router.navigate['/things']
```

Comment: You can do a great deal for the quality of your post or how that works. In this istance, I might elaborate on the pathing of routes, since the asker doesn't seem to understand pathing.

Answer (score 0):

So you should be able to check for the id of the thing in the ActivatedRoute params to get the context if the component is creating or editing a component. If there is a param['thingId'] then go to ../../ otherwise go to ../

Answer (score 0):

May be this idea a bit old school but I am sure it will work and is quite simplistic to implement. You can add query param called 'source' and navigate to 'source once the operation is done.